# WP7 - dynamic creation of PivotItem with listbox

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, pivot

I have this code in MainPage.xaml:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="first">
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

And I need to create N PivotItem's in runtime with such model. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your PivotItem delaration be a Static Resource.

```
<UserControl.Resources>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MyPivotItemTemplate">
   <controls:PivotItem Header="first" >
                <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItem}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PivotItem>
</DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then in your Pivot declaration use it as a template for your items.

```
<Pivot .... ItemsTemplate="{StaticResource MyPivotItemTemplate}" Items="{Binding MyCollectionInDataContext}"
```

This way, each time you add something to a `MyCollectionInDataContext`, a `PivotItem` is created according to your defined template.

Answer (score 3):

I actually did something similar today. You can apply the `DataTemplate` model to both the `PivotItem` and the `ListBox` that appears in the `PivotItem`. Try this out:

```
<controls:Pivot Name="PivotControl" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItemBinding}">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Put your header bindings here"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
     <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItem}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           </ListBox>
       </DataTemplate>
   </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

In this code, a `PivotItem` will be created for each item you bind to it, and its corresponding `ListBox` will be populated with the data from the collection in the same ItemSource.

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way than defining a `UserControl` and figuring out the binding for that...

Most of the complexity here is in the `ItemTemplate` - move the `ItemTemplate` into the ResourceDictionary for that page and apply it to all your ListBoxes. You can even move the template to  App.xaml if you use it in many pages/controls.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
...
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
...
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

At design-time you would simply call this up in each pivot item:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="first">
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" 
      Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItems}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemDataTemplate}"/>
</controls:PivotItem>
<controls:PivotItem Header="second">
    <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox2" 
      Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding OtherListBoxItems}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemDataTemplate}"/>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

If you need to do this at runtime from code, you can pull the "MyItemDataTemplate" `ItemTemplate` object from the page's `ResourceDictionary` and apply it to the new ListBox you create.

Answer (score 0):

first i created a user control

UserControl

```
 <UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="480" Background="Transparent">

 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <ListBox x:Name="listUser" Margin="20,0,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>

</Grid>

         </UserControl>
```

after in xaml

.cs

```
                pivotItem = new PivotItem();
                pivotItem.Header = "Pivot";

                UserControl user = new UserControl();
                user.DataContext = list;
                user.listUser.ItemsSource = list;

                pivotItem.Content = null;
                pivotItem.Content = user;
                pivotfather.Items.Add(pivotItem);
```